# Dataframe fill up a column values by finding the occurence of an other one in an other Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As you may have understood, my question is quite specific...
So I have 2 dataframes with a column which could be seen as a "Pivot" column.
All the values of this Pivot column are unique.
Our goal is to add a new column to the first Dataframe containing the value of a column in the second one.

This is what I tried for now, it unfortunately didn't work :/

```
df1['NewColumn] = '0'  //I created the first column and set a default value

df1.loc[df2['PivotCol'] == df1['PivotCol'], 'NewColumn'] = df2.loc[df2['PivotCol'] == df['PivotCol'], 'ColumnToMergeTo1stDataframe'].iloc[0]
```

NewColumn is the newly created column in df1 which will be containing the value of ColumnToMergeTo1stDataframe which is in the df2...

I hope that my problem is clear, don't hesitate to ask questions if it was not.

Last but not least, sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Col Pivot', 'Col to Merge']], on='Col Pivot', how='left')
```

A panda merge made the job :)